# Thread in Android method onCreate() still stops the UiThread in 10% of the cases

Tags: android, multithreading, ui-thread

This is my onCreate method of my first activity of my app. It initalizes all Widgets and then starts a Thread to load model data from the internet. In some cases, when the network is really slow or not responding, the `"initializeModelThread"` seems to take the whole CPU and doesnt allow the onCreate Methode to finish.

In one case I saw that `Log.v("Time...)` was called after 300 ms, but the screen remained black for about 20 seconds until a HttpException stopped the `initalizeModelThread`. You already can see that I set the Priority of the Thread to low.

Would the use of AsyncTask help in this case? Do u have any other thoughts about that issue?

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        initializeWidgets();

        Thread threadInstance = new Thread(initializeModelThread);
        threadInstance.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        threadInstance.start();

        Log.v("Time", "Difference from start " + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I used the google geo reverse coding feature (GeoCoder) in "initializeWidgets", which downloaded data from the web. It was really fast in 90 % of the cases. Now there never was such a delay again while starting after moving that download into a AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` would not make a difference here.

Instead of creating the thread on the `onCreate()` method, do it on the `onStart()` method.